# Remove consecutive duplicates for a certain time difference on same date using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
|name  |date       |time    | 
|Jay   |02/10/2020 |12:00:10|
|Jay   |02/10/2020 |12:23:50|
|Ben   |02/12/2020 |11:00:20|
|Ben   |02/12/2020 |11:40:30|
|Sky   |16/12/2020 |15:20:10|
```

The table contains names of people who logged in at specific times. I want to keep only one copy of the row for a specific person if they logged in again within 30 mins. There can be more than 2 entries within a period of 30mins. Expected result is as below.

Jay logged in again within 30mins so he has only one entry. Whereas Ben logged in after 30mins again so there are still 2 entries. It doesn't matter which row for the name is deleted.

```
|name  |date       |time    | 
|Jay   |02/10/2020 |12:00:10|
|Ben   |02/12/2020 |11:00:20|
|Ben   |02/12/2020 |11:40:30|
|Sky   |16/12/2020 |15:20:10|
```

I tried grouping the date and time to one datetime and then tried to find the time difference but it wasn't helpful. I also tried using shift() but don't know how would that be possible if multiple entries within 30 mins are present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`df.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
In [4586]: df['new'] = df.groupby(['name', 'date'])['time'].shift()
In [4590]: df['time_diff'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].astype(str)) - pd.to_timedelta(df['new'].astype(str))).dt.total_seconds().div(60).abs()

In [4596]: df = df[df.time_diff.gt(30) | df.time_diff.isna()][['name', 'date', 'time']]

In [4597]: df
Out[4597]: 
  name        date      time
0  Jay  02/10/2020  12:00:10
2  Ben  02/12/2020  11:00:20
3  Ben  02/12/2020  11:40:30
4  Sky  16/12/2020  15:20:10
```